# SQL Server service automatically stops after starting

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with my SQL Server 2014 Express version. It worked fine until now. I can't get it working because SQL Server service automatically stops immediately after I start it. I'm trying to start it from Sql Server Configuration Manager. When I open it I see that SQL Server service is stopped, I re-run it and the service don't give me any error while starting. Then after pressing F5 to refresh the screen it's stopped again ...

Here are some error logs from the starting operation. 
Can someone explain to me what had happened ?

Thanks

[Error log 1](http://www.filedropper.com/errorlog)

[Error log 2](http://www.filedropper.com/errorlog_1)

[Error log Fd](http://www.filedropper.com/fd_1)

Comment: From the log it looks like your _model_ database is been corrupted and needs to be restored or recreated, but I flagged this for migration to [dba.se] as you should get better answers on that site.

Comment: This question is a bit off-topic here. [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) are better places for questions like this. (In this case, I recommend Database Administrators)